# What was the 2nd best selling computer ever?

Tags: history, commodore

It's widely known that the Commodore 64 was the best-selling single model of personal computer. Which computer make & model got second place?

To clarify, I'm looking for an objective answer about a particular make & model, not a nuanced answer arguing for backwards compatibility or what constitutes minor vs. major revisions. As an example of potential answers, not knowing where the numbers actually break out, I might list the following myself (in no particular order): Atari 800xl, Apple //e, Amiga 500, Commodore 128, IBM PC(5150), XT(5160), Macintosh Plus, ZX Spectrum, etc.

(References with well-researched sales estimates will be nice.)

Comment: Are you using the branding as the way to determine what counts as a particular machine? There are some machines that are the same thing but branded differently in different places, and others which have a different branding with a translated ROM. There are some with the same name that are different (I think; I can't think of the name of the one that I'm thinking of).

Comment: I am not using branding. I'm using make & model. If there was different localized branding, the branding in the dominant region can be used to describe the same machine that existed in multiple regions.

Comment: Fitting the data to a particular answer using many nuances seems like a way to not get to an objective answer. Plus I'm 99% certain the correct answer is in my list of potentials, though available sales data may lead to some over-lapping 3-way tie or some such. Really, a few sentences and supporting sales data should be the best answer here.

Comment: Actually I wouldn't be surprised if it were the PCW as they sold a total of 8m of those; I just don't know to what extent refreshes prior to the PCW16 were just case changes, like the C64C — which was branded as that, on the box, distinctly from the unsuffixed C64 — and to what extent they were actually hardware revisions (other than board revisions and IC changes as, again, the C64 did both. The later SID isn't even fully compatible re:PCM tricks).

Comment: Probably every single model of the iPhone outsells the C64. Apple sold 77 million of them in the last quarter alone.

Answer (score 9):

Commodore famously inflated their sales numbers, so while you'll find many resources claiming 25 or 30 million 64's sold, it appears the number is closer to 17 million.

Behind that are two machines that sold about 5 million units:

- the Apple II was on the market for years, with reasonable sales well into the IBM era
- the Spectrum was a huge seller in the UK

And in third:

The Atari 8-bit requires special mention here. During its main run, it is estimated to have sold about 2.5 million machines, mostly in the US. However, the line had several "rebirths" as it entered new markets, first in western Europe, and then again in eastern Europe. Estimates on sales during this late period are very hard to come by, and various commenters put the total during this period anywhere from 1 to 2 million, which would put total sales anywhere from 3 to 5 million.

Others were generally much less:

- TI99 ~2.5mm
- Amstrad CPC ~2.5mm, Wiki says 3mm.
- VIC-20 ~2mm
- TRS-80 ~1.mm
- BBC Micro ~1mm

Most of these numbers were compiled by Jeremy Reimer and are available in XL format on [his site](http://jeremyreimer.com/m-item.lsp?i=137). However, I don't think he dove too deep into these numbers, so take them with some grain of salt.

Comment: Where did the original 8088-based IBM PC (model 5150) come in?

Comment: I guess we're pushing up against the bounds of what @BrianH counts as a "single model" with these numbers, particularly re: the Apple II, the CPC and the Spectrum, but I'm on your side of the debate. Especially just adding some RAM and/or a disk drive doesn't feel like a big deal. But Brian would have to clarify.

Comment: What does "mm" mean?

Comment: It also might help to qualify what counts as a personal computer.  The Atari 2600 could program a dialect of BASIC using the keypad controllers, after all.

Comment: I suspect that of the Apple II's, it was the //e or the //c that posted the largest single model sales number. Likewise the Atari 800xl.

Comment: mm is millions, I used it in the financials world, I'm not sure where it comes from originally.

Comment: @BrianH - just to further confuse the Atari number, there was an 800XE that sold only in eastern europe, and I believe it makes up the majority of late-date sales.

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz I'm not sure but I think there is no fundamental distinction between the 800XE and the 65XE. Just a nameplate.

Comment: @BrianH - I know, but there seems to be some serious hair-splitting below, so I wanted to mention it in case it is seen as two models.

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz I'm guessing the 800xl outsold all other Atari 8-bits. Also is the 5MM Spectrums just the ZX, or does it include ZX80/ZX81/128/whatever else was called a "Spectrum"?

Comment: The 16kb, 48kb, 128kb, +2, +2a and +3 machines, the first three from Sinclair, the final three from Amstrad are usually just all considered 'the Spectrum' in aggregate. They differ in memory size and built-in storage medium, the 128kb onwards has a sound chip and at some point the ULA is switched for a CPLD with slightly different timing. But if you bought a Spectrum magazine with a tape on the cover you'd expect that tape to work on all of those machines other than probably the 16kb because it wasn't around for long and was easy to upgrade if you were still holding onto it years later.

Comment: @Tommy - except, as a Spectrum owner at the time of its introduction, I'd definitely consider the 128K and subsequent versions a different model: they added substantial new features (bank switching and an AY sound chip), changed the user interface (providing a new version of BASIC that didn't use the old single key token entry system), and were even apparently primarily designed by a non-Sinclair supplier (Investronica SA, the Spanish distributor of Sinclair computers).

Comment: MSX computer sales figures are also in the 5 million mark, at least according to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MSX). However that number is not for a single maker/model, but for all the MSX-compatible models together.

Comment: @Jules my family's machine was a +2a, and although there were maybe half a dozen games for the 128kb machines only, right at the end (including Robocop 2 maybe?), you'd use most software having no idea until it loaded which Spectrum it was nominally for, expecting no difference than some music and maybe less multiloading. Software would just be for the Spectrum and you were as likely to play Manic Miner or Deathchase 3d or Chaos as anything else.

Comment: What constitutes an Atari 8-bit computer can become very clouded. If you include the XE Game System - which was a 65XE with a detachable keyboard sold as a game console - then there's at least 100,000 of them sold. Whether or not they were already included in the official number, I don't know. If you add the Atari 5200 to the mix - since it was a keyboardless Atari 400 but with its chipset mapped differently and thus not exactly compatible - then that's another 1 million - 1.5 million more units sold.

Answer (score 8):

I would say the raspberry pi would be, according to https://www.techspot.com/amp/news/73709-raspberry-pi-model-b-arrives-time-pi-day.html

"To date, over 19 million Raspberry Pi computers have been sold. Out of which, the Raspberry Pi 3 accounts for over 9 million units"

Comment: Despite having deleted my answer because Brian said he wanted to know only about contemporaries of the C64, I still think this is correct.

Comment: The question currently doesn't put any kind of restriction on when the computer was sold. Given that, the Raspberry Pi looks kind of pathetic set against nearly any version of the iPhone.

Comment: The iPhone doesn't qualify. See @Tommy 's answer below.

Comment: Don't see my answer necessarily, so much as @BrianH's comment on it. Maybe my StackOverflow etiquette is askew but I took Brian's comment "I was more thinking of computer models that coincided with the C64 lifespan of 1982-1994, which makes this question more distinctly about Retrocomputing." as implicitly modifying the question. I guess it depends on whether you think the person that asked the question is definitive as to what the question means once it's been written. As a law school graduate I decline to take a position on that; it's a bit too civil-versus-common-law.

Answer (score 2):

Hard to be sure; the old translucent iMac G3 (gumdrop models)
were slightly different, but sold for five or six years, circa 2 million
per year.   Should we count colors as differences?  CPU speeds?
Included ports (graphite and later had the Firewire ports)?

That was on the cusp of computing taking off in the mass market,
not just gamesters and enthusiasts.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that the Commodore 64 was probably the 2nd best selling computer ever.

I don't have the numbers to back this up, but I believe at least one model of the iPhone has outsold the Commodore 64. Apple doesn't release numbers for specific iPhone models so only they know for certain.

Of the list you gave, I'd say the Amiga 500, which sold 6 million units, putting the entire Apple II series and ZX Spectrum series in third and fourth place.

The Apple II and ZX Spectrum series each sold no more than 5 million but individual models sold less than that obviously.

Comment: Oh, unambiguously so. Apple sold 13m 6s and 6s+s in its first weekend — https://www.engadget.com/2015/09/28/apple-iphone-6s-sales-record/ . So that's at least 6.5m of either one in three days of a handset that is still on sale three years later.

Comment: I would say that the iPhone doesn't count for the same reason the NES doesn't, as it was never sold as a "computer", but rather as a "smartphone".

Comment: @PaulHumphreys following up on whether it had ever been sold as a computer, the 2007 keynote that introduced the iPhone is also the one in which Jobs announced: "So, today, we’ve added to the Mac and the iPod. We’ve added Apple TV and now iPhone. And you know, the Mac is the only one that you think really of as a computer. ... So we’re announcing today we’re dropping the computer from our name, and from this day forward, we’re gonna be known as Apple Incorporated". Apple was so sure they didn't want to sell it as a 'computer' that they changed the name of the company!

Comment: Marketing can call it whatever they want but they can't change reality.

Comment: Isn’t that one of the issues we face : that marketers think they understand reality ....

Comment: @PaulHumphreys The iPhone very definitely is a computer.

Comment: @JeremyP That's your opinion. The manufacturers opinion is that it is not. Is a washing machine a computer then? Most have microprocessors now and run programs. You could modify the processor in them to run programs of your own devising.

Comment: @PaulHumphreys It's a computer. There is no doubt about it. The fact that you can even emulate a Commodore 64 on it with better performance than the original should be a clue.

Comment: If smartphones are considered computers, then shouldn't games consoles also be considered so? Then the C64 isn't even nearly the most popular computer of all time. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_best-selling_game_consoles

Comment: If a consumer can load a Tiny Basic interpreter on it and type in and run trek (or similar), an iPhone could be considered just as much a computer as an Altair or Apple 1.  Note that the App Store contains multiple interpreter apps for various educational programming languages.